# matlab histogram, how to set overflow value and make all values greater than it in one bar

Tags: matlab, histogram, bar-chart, matlab-figure

cause Office Excel can set a overflow value, and make all values greater than it in one bar, I really want to make some histogram like the following one in matlab. Hope someone can save me...
[image: excel-hist-overflow-value]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `histcounts` to get the histogram data, and then plot it back with `bar`.

Here is a simple example:

```
data = randi(100,1000,1);
[bin,edge] = histcounts(data);
overflow = 50;
lastBin = sum(bin(edge(2:end)>overflow))
bar([bin(edge(2:end)<=overflow) lastBin]);
```

Then you can change the last x-tick label with:

```
cut_ind = find(edge(1:end)<=overflow,1,'last');
xtlbls = cellstr(strcat('[',num2str(edge(1:cut_ind-1).'),...
    ',', num2str(edge(2:cut_ind).'),']'))
xtlbls(end+1) = {['>' num2str(overflow)]}
xticklabels(xtlbls)
```

[image]